# See what (javascript) function is used when you press a button

Tags: javascript

Let's say you have a button and a javascript function onclick. Is it possible in (for example with Firebug) to see which javascript is called and how the script looks like when you click this button?

I know how to place a breakpoint, but then you have to search it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

select it is possible (excet for some advanced scenarios - for instance with SharePoint Ribbon).
you can use FF Firebug or IE 8+ Dev Toolbar. in IE you need to press F12 button on a keyboard "select element" (arrow-like button in a top left corner of a tool ) and then pick your button on the page.

Comment: Chrome's Developer Tools will let you inspect any event listeners that are attached to DOM Nodes. Firebug offers similar functionality, but I don't think IE 8's tool will let you do anything like that.

Comment: Chrome isn't officially supported by SP2010 (and wont work at all with SP2007), I would advise using IE's developer tools.